# DOM Javascript eliminación de columna

Tags: javascript, funciones, dom, function

Para eliminar la primera columna de la tabla del siguiente documento html.
¿cómo sería la forma correcta trabajando con DOM?

```js
function del_Col(){
  var elimina2=document.getElementById("sampleTable");
  var eliminaCol=elimina2.getElementsByTagName("td");
  eliminaCol[0].parentNode.removeChild(eliminaCol[0]);
}
```

```html
<table id="sampleTable" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row1 cell1</td>
      <td>Row1 cell2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row2 cell1</td>
      <td>Row2 cell2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<a href="javascript:del_Col()">Del col</a>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Hola una de las posibles formas de hacerlo

```js
let boton = document.querySelector('a');
boton.onclick = del_Col;
function del_Col(){
    let elimina2=document.getElementById("sampleTable");
    let eliminaCol=elimina2.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (let i = 0; i < eliminaCol.length; i++) {
        let eliminaCel=eliminaCol[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        eliminaCol[i].removeChild(eliminaCel[0]);       
    }    
}
```

```html
<table id="sampleTable" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row1 cell1</td>
      <td>Row1 cell2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row2 cell1</td>
      <td>Row2 cell2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<a href="javascript:">Del col</a>
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Así es como lo haría:
por vavor lea los comentarios en el código

```js
//selecciona la table
var tabla = document.getElementById("sampleTable");
//todos los elementos tr de la tabla
var trs = tabla.querySelectorAll("tr");

//al hacer click en borrar
borrar.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  //borra el segundo td (index 1) de cada tr. 
  trs.forEach(tr=>{tr.removeChild(tr.childNodes[1]); })
})
```

```html
<table id="sampleTable" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr><td>Row0 cell0</td><td>Row0 cell1</td><td>Row0 cell2</td><td>Row0 cell3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row1 cell0</td><td>Row1 cell1</td><td>Row1 cell2</td><td>Row1 cell3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row2 cell0</td><td>Row2 cell1</td><td>Row2 cell2</td><td>Row2 cell3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table><br>
<p id="borrar">Borra la segunda columna!</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Segun la estructura de su tabla, solo debe asegurarse de capturar la primera celda `td` dentro de cada fila `tr` y borrarla del DOM

```js
function del_Col(){
   let td = document.querySelectorAll('#sampleTable tr td:nth-child(1)');
   // selecionar el primer td dentro de cada tr en tu tabla #sampleTable
   td.forEach( (el)=>{ el.remove() } ) // y remueves cada una del DOM 
}
```

```html
<table id="sampleTable" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row1 cell1</td>
      <td>Row1 cell2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row2 cell1</td>
      <td>Row2 cell2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<button onclick="del_Col()">Del</button>
```